# Update / Change the image of SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sktexture

Is it possible to update/change the image of an `SKSpriteNode`?
The code below does not work:

```
var boss1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "boss1.png")
boss1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "boss2.png")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you created the `SKSpriteNode`

```
var boss1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "boss1.png")
```

you can update the `texture` property like that

```
boss1.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "boss2.png")
```

Here's an example from my Playground

[image]

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing right now is creating a new instance and then use a local variable to reference it. Then, the previous one's retain count will drop to zero and be deallocated. You will have to know what is your intention. Based on the documentation, I think you can change it and the property is `texture`:

> This method creates a new texture object from the image file and
>   assigns that texture to the texture property. The size property of the
>   sprite is set to the dimensions of the image. The color property is
>   set to white (1.0,1.0,1.0).

Here is how you can change it:

```
boss1.texture = UIImage(...)
```

Here is the link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKSpriteNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKSpriteNode/texture